# needs nested_form example

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I give up. I'm trying to build a simple nested form with 2 models following Railscasts #196 episode and doesn't work. Can someone send a working example please so I can test on my environment. I'm using 3.1.0

For example when I try to build 3 questions on the form only 1 question field appears, then survey_id is never passed across.

I would appreciate your help after 2 days and nights on it. I got missing something really big. Thanks

Model

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  attr_accessible :name, :questions_attributes
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  attr_accessible :survey_id, :name
end
```

Controller

```
def new
@survey = Survey.new
4.times { @survey.questions.build }

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @survey }
end
end

def create
@survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])

respond_to do |format|
  if @survey.save
    format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @survey, status: :created, location: @survey }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
     <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<%= fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label :name, "Question"  %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

<br /><br />
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code, we cannot help you debug it otherwise.

Comment: This looks right to me, have you checked that survey_id column exists in the table questions? Also, watch what happens when you submit the form in the server console.

Comment: Thanks @cjm2671 `Parameters: "survey"=>{"name"=>"Survey test"}, "questions"=>{"name"=>"Q1"}, "commit"=>"Create Survey"}
  SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "surveys" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?), ["name", "Survey test"], ["updated_at"]` survey_id is missing from the questions

Comment: You need survey_id on the questions, i.e. rails generate migration AddSurveyIdToQuestions survey_id:integer; rake db:migrate

Comment: survey_id already exists

Comment: Are you sure? (This isn't what it says in your previous comment unless I misunderstood).

Comment: I meant that it in server log it should mention survey_id right? At the end survey_id column exists but doesn't get populated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4053/discussion-between-gaelle-and-cjm2671)